# Having numbers as column names instead of string values in R exported excel

Tags: r

I exported an excel in r without headers.

```
df = read.xlsx('D:/hotel rates/Yoho 5th Lane Signature 2799850.xls', sheetIndex = 1, header = FALSE)
```

Then changed the colnames as the second row values.

```
colnames(df) =df[2,]
```

But my column names appeared as numbers as follows.

[image]

Actually I want the second row as my colnames. Can any one fix this?

I think thereis some kind of factor level in data. when I run `df[2,2]`the console shows the following.`

[image]

Comment: What about `colnames(df) <- as.character(df[2,])`?

Comment: similar to https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: No good the result is same...

Comment: Please give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: How about `startRow=2,colNames=TRUE` in your `read.xlsx` call?

Comment: How about `colnames(df) = unlist(df[2,])`?

Comment: Thanks every one .. found the answer..
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)